# ERROR: syntax error while executing query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting a SQL query and getting this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "rental_date"
>   LINE 4: select I.store_id,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP rental_date) ...

This is my code:

```
select 
    store_id, Month_Name, max(RentOrder) as maximum_order 
from 
    (select 
         I.store_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP rental_date) as Month_Name,
         count(rental_id) as RentOrder 
     from 
         Rental R 
     inner join 
         Inventory I on R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
     group by 
         I.store_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP rental_date) ) as T 
group by 
    store_id, Month_Name
```

I have checked the names of the variables thoroughly matching my database.

However, it is still throwing the syntax issue. Assistance would be appreciated to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just remove timestam from your query A and rest of the things are fine

```
 select 
        store_id, Month_Name, max(RentOrder) as maximum_order 
    from 
        (select 
             I.store_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM rental_date) as Month_Name,
             count(rental_id) as RentOrder 
         from 
             Rental R 
         inner join 
             Inventory I on R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
         group by 
             I.store_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM rental_date) ) as T 
    group by 
        store_id, Month_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `rental_date` already is a `timestamp`. Remove the `TIMESTAMP` in the `EXTRACT()` calls.

```
...
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM rental_date)
...
```